# Calling 'normal' member functions from JS prototypes

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

I'm trying to create a JS class, where each object will contain a member, `verify_function` which will be supplied by a constructor at the time of creation. Then at some point in time, the prototype functions will call this `verify_function`.

This is what my code looks like:

```
var ClassName = function(verify_callback) {
    this.verify_function = verify_callback;
}

ClassName.prototype.functionName = function() {
    this.verify_function(); //problem lies here
}
```

I'm trying to create the object like this:

```
var objectName = new ClassName(function() {
    console.log('This should be printed!');
})
```

On executing the code, it says:

```
TypeError: this.verify_function is not a function
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Tushar, sorry for the typo. That mistake is not there in the code.

Comment: if you resolve that issue, it should work. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/eLbzbdnh/)

Comment: Where is `self.verify_function` coming from? I don't see that in any of the posted code.

Comment: You're missing a `)` at the end of the `objectName` assignment. When I fix that, your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/pmw9pxjs/1/

Comment: But maybe that's another copying error, because I got a syntax error from it.

Comment: @Rajesh, shockingly, it's not working. This all code is in a node module, and I'm doing `module.exports = ClassName'`, and then calling the code in the client like this: `var ClassName = require("ClassName")`, if it helps

Comment: @Barmar, yes, I typed the code in the browser. Sublime Text makes me lazy

Comment: Since the code works when loaded directly into a browser, it seems like your problem is specific to using `require()` to load the file.

Comment: Its difficult to give you solution/suggestion as code here provides limited visibility. I'd though suggest you to check if path and name are proper.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong about your code. It works perfectly fine.